# shibboleth and openssl version

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, shibboleth

I have a problem with shibboleth and openssl.
When I access a secure area it doesn't seem to take the .p12 key
i am using openssl verion 0.98 i tried to update it to version 1.1.1s
I have to use one of these version but I always encounter this error.
Can anyone help me?

```
ERROR OpenSSL : error code: 50856204 in ../crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c, line 349
ERROR OpenSSL : error data: Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
CRIT Shibboleth.Application : error building CredentialResolver: Unable to load private key from file (/path/to/file/file.p12).
```